# Dependency Injection error after deploying Azure functions to portal

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I am facing an error while running azure functions after deployment. 
They are working fine from locally.
but after deployment they are throwing exception.

I have tried by running into Azure portal.

Here is the error.

[image]

Please help me .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Here is a related issue which is fixed: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4237 Can you please open a new issue with the details requested in the issue template. Also, please update Azure Functions Core Tools to the latest version to be able to use same version of azure functions runtime locally as deployed in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the Function Runtime version in the Application Settings.
Change the `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to `2.0.12408`, if you want other release versions, you could get the latest release [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases).

And this should have been fixed from the github [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4203#issuecomment-478124274), so please update the Core tools.